# Coloring a graph with odd number of vertices with k (which is close to Δ) colors in linear time

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, coloring

We have an undirected simple connected graph with odd number of vertices. We also know the number k which is actually the closest odd number greater than or equal to Δ. (So if Δ is even, k=Δ+1 else k=Δ.) i.e k is the least odd number that is greater than or equal to degrees of all vertices.

We want to find a linear time algorithm that colors the graph with k colors.

I am very new to graph coloring algorithms. I know that a greedy algorithm is actually linear time and can color the graph with Δ+1. But I can't guarantee I can color it with k=Δ when Δ is odd. Also, we probably should use all the information the question gives us. i.e using odd number of vertices somehow, but greedy algorithm don't use this extra information.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 4):

### Restating the problem:

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a **connected** graph with an odd number of vertices, and $\Delta(G)$ is also odd.
>
> describe a linear algorithm that colors $G$, in $\Delta$ colors.

Denote $\vert V\vert =2m + 1,\Delta(G)=2k + 1$.

I'll use the following claim, which is equivalent to the definition of [degeneracy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)#Definitions_and_equivalences) of a graph, which I will not proof rigorously:

> If $V$ has an ordering such that $$\forall i\in [2m+1]\ \  \vert N_G(v_i)\cap \{v_j\in V\mid j>i\}\vert \leq t$$
> Then $\chi(G)\leq t + 1$.

1. Where $N_G(v_i)=\{u\in V\mid (u,v)\in E\}$
2. $\chi(G)$ is the minimal number of colours one needs to colour $G$
3. $[2m+1]:=\{1,2,3,....2m+1\}$

I'll use this claim with $t=2k$

### Finding such ordering in linear time

1. Pick a vertex $v_1$ with a minimal degree.
2. for $i = 1$ to $i = \vert V\vert $: pick a neighbor of $v_i$
3. Color the graph using the greedy algorithm, where you color the vertices according to the **reverse** ordering you found.

**Explaining the first and second step**

by the [Handshaking lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Handshaking_lemma), not all vertices could have an odd degree.
Therefore $\exists v\in V \ \ s.t\ \  \deg(v)\leq 2k + 1\ \ $   (Since $\Delta(G)$ is odd)

One can repeat this process, Since $N_G(v)>0$ since $G$ is connected, by picking the next vertex in the ordering, to be some vertex in $N_G(v)$ (which is not empty).

When $v_i$ was picked, it had at least one neighbor in the set$[i-1]$.
Since $\deg(v_i)\leq\Delta(G)= 2k+1$, we get $$\vert N_G(v_i)\cap \{v_j\in V\mid j>i\}\vert \leq 2k$$

**Explaining the third step (sketch of proof for the claim)**

When the greedy algorithm colors the vertex $v_i$, it has at most $2k$ neighbors that were already colored. (Correctness of ordering)

Therefore, the greedy algorithm could pick at least one color, out of the $2k+1$ colors, that was not used, and color $v_i$ with it.

### Remark

The statement is wrong when $G$ is not required to be connected.

A counter-example would be $K_4$ with isolated vertex.